# What is best suited condition when interface is used instead of inheritance in c#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I am wondering what is best condition to use interface instead of inheritance in c#.

Comment: usualy you inherit and implement interface. What's your question then?

Comment: Not quite sure what the point is of the question, but if I should try to answer it, I'd say that interface is what your class can do, and inheritance is what your class is.

Comment: @scherling, I'm working on a game where i have three state 1, state 2, state 3.All are relate to each other.So what is best way to communicate these three state ,Using inheritance or Interface?
I think you got my point